# Microsoft Word 2013 Change citation language

Tags: microsoft-word, language, microsoft-word-2013

How do I change the default language for every citation in my Microsoft Word 2013 document?

I have an English installation, with Dutch editing language enabled, and I wrote the document in Dutch.

When adding the biography I changed the field code from `BIBLIOGRAPHY  \l 1033` to `BIBLIOGRAPHY  \l 1043`, which solves my biography (see [Change the language of fields in Microsoft Word](https://superuser.com/questions/155752/change-the-language-of-fields-in-microsoft-word)).

My problem is for every citation I have (over 50) that they are also in English. To get them all into Dutch I have to change the field codes from `CITATION Str14 \l 1033` to `CITATION Str14 \l 1043` also, 50+ times.

Is there a way to do this automatic and by default at once?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the field codes are visible (Alt-F9) then use FInd/Replace. It might be as simple as finding 1033 and replacing by 1043. Then use ctrl-A to select the document and F9 to update all the field results. If changing the language number is enough, that should do it.