# Force the chosen Locale for a field with numeric data or formulae in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, locale, field-codes

I've a simple function: `{=B2*C2 \# "-#.##0,00"}` in a table in Word. However, this gives the result as `2.345,67`, because I live in The Netherlands. Now I need to share this document with English colleagues and want the formatting of such formulas (I've plenty) to show as `2,345.67`, i.e. British or US Locale. I can do that by using `{=B2*C2 \# "-#.##0,00"}`, but then I need to maintain two versions of the document and update each and every field.

I prefer to be able to set the locale some central way, but setting the locale for the document, or through proofing tools, doesn't help, and  [this suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/155752/change-the-language-of-fields-in-microsoft-word), i.e. using locale like `\l 2057` for English, gives a syntax error.

I can clearly change the formatting string by hand, though I prefer to use the language setting. Same does not apply to fields being read: if I change the field in `B2` to use dots for decimal as opposed to commas, it fails to calculate properly.

Changing the locale of the whole computer helped, but this is not a long-term solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are are number of problems in this area and none of them is particularly easy to solve.

In some respects, the main problem is not the one you actually describe, i.e. that the formatting doesn't work, but the problem  that when a user types a number into the table, it is "fixed", i.e. after you have typed

```
1234,56
```

there isn't a completely reliable mechanism in Word to change that to

```
1234.56
```

and Word will recognise the number differently depending on whether Windows control panel has the decimal point character set as "." or ",".

If you are creating a document with no such values (just empty cells) *and* you are going to send the "form" to a US/UK user who will type in the values *and* it is only then going to be used by UK/US users, there are a couple of things you can do.

Otherwise, AFAIK, you either have to force people to enter the data in a very unnatural way or you have once a user has typed in 1234.56, or you have to make it easy to convert all numbers to the other culture's format. At its simplest, you could use a wildcard find/replace to replace something like

```
([0-9]),([0-9])
```

to

```
\1.\2
```

(or the other way around), assuming that that will not modify any other things that happen to look like numbers. And you would probably need to wrap that in a VBA macro.

As for the formatting switches, the only really reliable way of dealing with that is not to use them and rely completely on how Word formats numbers by default. (FWIW, when people put "#" placeholders in Word numeric formats, it is sometimes because they have come from an Excel background and they have not realised that they just do not need them).

However, if you have to use numeric formats, what you then have to do is get the correct "decimal point" and "thousands separator" characters into the format. And by that, I mean the same characters as are used in Windows control panel on the machine where the document is being edited.

There isn't a completely reliable built-in way of doing that using fields. You could use VBA to get the relevant characters from Windows. Alternatively, you can try "faking it" using some nested fields along the following lines:

```
{ IF 1/2 = 0,5 "{ SET POINT "," }{ SET GROUP "." }" "{ SET POINT "." }{ SET GROUP "," }" }
```

(remember that *all* the {  } have to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows desktop Word)

then, instead of

```
{=B2*C2 \# "-#.##0,00"}
```

you use

```
{=B2*C2 \# "-#{ GROUP }##0{ POINT }00"}
```

Alternatively, you could define your formats at the beginning of the document, e.g.

```
{ SET FORMAT1 "-#{ GROUP }##0{ POINT }00" }
```

then use

```
{=B2*C2 \# "{ FORMAT1 }"}
```

Obviously, this approach as stated will not deal with an arbitrary locale (for example, some locales use a non-breaking space character as the thousands separator) or unusual settings in control panel, but they may be enough for NL/US/UK.

Unfortunately, that is the "easy" problem to solve. If what you actually want is to fix everything so that all your users (NL/UK/US) enter and see the same formatting, regardless of their Windows settings, that is actually a much harder problem to solve. Suppose you decide everyone should enter and see the US format, e.g. `1,234,567.89`

The problem then is that Word will not recognize "1234.56" correctly on a system set up with typical NL settings. The only things you could possibly do (IMO) to deal with that would be...

a. avoid any user-entered data, or constrain users to enter whole-number data only

b. temporarily modify the relevant Windows settings on the user's system, perhaps using VBA, if that is not ruled out by security restrictions.

I am not sure it is even worth trying to provide a solution to either of those options.

However, it is perhaps worth listing some of the things a general-purpose solution to this problem might have to take into account, as follows:

1. The basic problem is that Word's numeric formatting relies mainly on the settings in Windows Settings/Control Panel. In fact Word's implementation is so old that it only honors a few of those settings. For example, it will do digit grouping in groups of three regardless of what you set in control panel. As you already discovered, you cannot influence numeric display using a locale switch such as `\l 2057` or by applying a proofing language (which does actually work to a certain extent with dates. Even if you could apply a proofing language, you would still have to work out how to change it.
2. desktop and online versions of Word behave differently. AFAICS at the moment the web version of Word leaves the field results as they are, regardless of any locale settings. Of course that could change over time, and "device" versions of Word may behave differently. The Mac Desktop version behaves in much the same way as the Windows version, but modifying the Mac settings would need different code from the Windows version.
3. There isn't just a "format" problem. There is also a "how do you type your numbers" problem and a "recognition" problem.
4. There is no convention in the number format string that lets you either *override* the values in Windows control panel, or even specify that you want to use the value specified in the Windows control panel.

What I mean by *override* is that you cannot do something like

```
{ DECIMAL "." }{ =10000/3 \# "###0<decimal>00" }
```

so Word would *always* use "." as the decimal point, regardless of the Windows settings.

What I mean by "use the value specified in the Windows control panel" is this: When you type a format such as

```
#,##0.00
```

then if "," is actually the decimal point character in Windows settings, the whole format string cannot behave as you might hope.

you arguably really want to use something like

```
#<thousands>##0<decimal>00
```

where Word actually picks up the value of  and  from Windows Control Panel.

5. Other than resorting to VBA, there is nothing in Word that lets you reliably discover the current values of the thousands separator character, decimal point character (or currency character string)
6. (probably not relevant in your case but worth mentioning for completeness) If you use SharePoint metadata to insert numeric values via content controls, you end up having to work with the "." convention for decimal points because that's the convention that XML uses and Word does not help you overcome it.
7. In numeric format strings, the "thousands separator character" is not positional. e.g. in the US/UK convention, formatting `1000000` with `\#",0"` gives you `1,000,000` , not `100000,0`
8. If you also need to enter/format currency data, addition settings apply. If you have a document with data in two or more different currencies, you have to accept that Word will only recognise one of them as a currency.
9. Word gets the value of one other special character from Windows control panel - the list separator character. It is usually either "," or ";". If you have formulas that use functions with parameters, you need to use the correct separator. (You may also need to use the correct separator in other field types such as TOC and EQ).
10. Trying to detect or evaluate the values of the three variable characters (decimal point, digit grouping separator, list separator) using field coding, is, I suspect, practically impossible in the general case. Even the approach I suggested above may result in a syntax error, particularly if you are doing a mailmerge where Word may flag a Syntax error that does not cause a problem in a normal document.

Comment: _"The basic problem is that Word's numeric formatting relies mainly on the settings in Windows Settings/Control Panel"_: indeed, and that's problematic, because it makes a Word document non-transferable. If someone in the UK would do a field-refresh, the numbers won't parse anymore. Thanks for such an extensive answer!!! I may actually go for a VBA solution, as that'll be easier to roll out over multiple documents.

Comment: @Abel - yes, if a VBA approach is an option for you things begin to look a bit more feasible. Although these days Microsoft is pushing its JS-based add on tech very hard, along with a general dumbing down of what features you can access (fields=bad, rich text content controls=good) so if that is also feasible for you, probably worth a look.